# Python, Brew, and MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, homebrew

I have been running python from a brew install. I went to install the mysql_python egg with setup tools (standard install according to mysql_python instructions) and it installed to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. The dependencies processed, etc.

Then I went to run python console. I can import other things (e.g. import django; print django.VERSION works) but when I import MySQLdb, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any insight? Thanks much.

Comment: Sounds like you are mixing native OSX Python and Brew Python somehow. Exact installation commands and output would be useful to solve this problem.

Comment: I think I did as well. Installation commands for mysql_python was very basic, just doing python setup.py build; python setup.py install. It seems that the installation of the egg was to python2.7, but the python console opens from brew's dir. Any ideas on how to untangle this conflation?

Comment: When you did python setup.py install was it using OSX native Python or Brew built Python?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In trying to duplicate your error I did the following (I assume, being a homebrewer, you have done the same).

1) `brew install python` To install Python 2.7
2) `brew install mysql` To install mysql to the system (needed for various drivers)
3) Configured mysql per homebrew's recommendations
4) Downloaded [mysql_python](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/mysql-python/1.2.3/)  and unzipped it
5) Installed mysql_python using `python setup.py install`
6) Tested it in an interactive session `python`, `import _mysql`

After walking through these steps on Lion, I was unable to reproduce your error.  Now... on to debugging your issue.

A few things to check:
1) In your terminal when you type `which python` does it point to your homebrew install?
2) Keep in mind that with homebrew the site-packages are not stored in the Cellar they are stored in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.  See [this](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python) post for more info on why.  I have not had to add the site-packages' location to my PATH, but you might give that a try.
3) The last thing I could suggest to try is in order to get easy_install to work with homebrew's python I had to add /usr/local/share/python to my PATH.

**EDIT**
After re-reading the error messages mainly after scrolling all the way to the right, I noticed that it was unable to load a mysql library.  A quick google search on that library made it seem that when installing mysql on OS X there can be difficulties linking to it.  Try and locate the file `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` and note down it's path.  After installing mysql via homebrew mine is : `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.14/lib`.  The common fix I have seen fix the environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  For more information where I got this check out [this](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/) site.  Using my path's as an example I would add this line to my .bash_profile

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.14/lib"`

If this does not work for you, I would strongly look into the possibility that mysql isn't installed correctly or is having issues.  With that mindset hopefully something will pop out at your.

Lastly, if you do not have any sql databaes yet, might I suggest uninstalling mysql and installing it via homebrew?  I am now having zero trouble with that setup.

Comment: 1. which python points to /usr/local/bin/python, which seems to be a symlink for the homebrew. One reason why I think this is true is that the error shows that the console is looking in the Cellar site-packages.     2. The Cellar directory /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages has the MySQL_python egg in it (just like the /usr/local/.../p2.7/s-p dir does)       3. /usr/local/share/python is already in my path

Comment: does it matter where i run 'python setup.py install' from?

Comment: @user592419: This is what I would have guessed.  I assumed it was calling the brewed python, if it wasn't I'm sure you'd be have lots of other problems.

Comment: @user592419: As long as the setup.py doesn't do anything abnormal - No.  In general the dist_tools that creates the setup.py is done so that it it will install all of contents in the executor's (found by the which python) site-packages.  After re-reading the error message I think it actually might be an issue with mysql, not homebrew / python.

Comment: @user592419: Check out my edit.  I may have found some useful information for you.

Comment: Awesome, it's working now. Following some of your suggestions, I then went and checked "which mysql" and found it was pointing to a different version. I changed my path so that it sees the cellar version of mysql, redid the python setup.py commands, and now it seems to be good. Thanks Adam.