# Python's MySQLdb can’t find libmysqlclient.dylib with Homebrewed MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, homebrew, mysql-python

## MySQL and Python installed with Homebrew

I installed MySQL and Python with Homebrew on OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite. My Python 2.7 is at  `python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/python` with a symlink to it at `/usr/local/bin/python`.

In `/usr/local/bin` there is a symlink:
`mysql -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/bin/mysql`

### The error

In the Python shell:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

So I tried:
`$ sudo unlink /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

followed by:
`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

and then (desperation over reason):
`$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib`

But in both cases `import MySQLdb` still tried to import `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`.

Then I tried:
`$ pip install -U MySQL-python`
and got:
`Requirement already up-to-date: MySQL-python in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

### Existing answers

Many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv) [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375199/python-brew-and-mysqldb) [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559699/python-mysqldb-and-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib) [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib) suggest manually making an explicit symlink to the library with a version number (in my case `libmysqlclient.20.dylib`). However, this seems crude and not future-proof, given the existing symlinks:

in `/usr/local/lib` there is
`libmysqlclient.dylib -> ../Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib`

and in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.9/lib` we find:
`libmysqlclient.20.dylib`

with a symlink in the same directory to it:
`libmysqlclient.dylib -> libmysqlclient.20.dylib`

### How to make Python forget `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`?

So how can I get Python to forget `/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib` and follow the correct symlink in in `/usr/local/lib` to `libmysqlclient.dylib`, without manually adding yet another symlink?

Comment: Followed same confused path - important difference is I think that the latest brew install gives libmysqlclient.20.dylib not 18 and reinstalling MySQL suggested by Aplusplus answered it for me too.

Comment: for me `pip install mysqlclient` solved the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solved my issue on my case:

```
$ pip uninstall MySQL-python
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

`MySQL-python` turned out to be very old (last commit was 7 years ago). `mysqlclient` is the modern version of it, with lots of improvements and bug fixes.

Comment: Yep. That's the issue! All over the internet there's "MySQL-python" as the way to go, but the commits tell the real story.

Comment: Mojave on OSX is/was problematic. Use of `brew install mysql-connector-c` installed libmysqlclient.18.dylib where it was expected.  Various "updated" software had `libmysqlclient.21.dylib` (and others) via brew and native installs. I opted to get the "18" version on system as MySQL on OSX breaks easily (10 years running) so opt for understandable, reversible, and logical fixes.  It is important to mention that Python+MySQL is turbulent on OSX, as is Python+OSX historically.  Not even (PIPENV like) virtual env will protect the user/app from volatility, local drivers/assets can fail too.

Answer (score 32):

I also encountered this problem. I uninstalled the MySQL-python, and then installed it.

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
pip install MySQL-python
```

---

**Update (based on comments)**

In some cases, you may need to perform the second (install) step in the following manner:

```
pip install --no-binary MySQL-python MySQL-python
```

The [`no-binary`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-no-binary) option is so that pip builds it fresh and links to the correct library:

> `--no-binary <format_control>`
>
> Do not use binary packages. Can be supplied multiple times, and each time adds to the existing value. Accepts either :all: to disable all binary packages, :none: to empty the set, or one or more package names with commas between them. Note that some packages are tricky to compile and may fail to install when this option is used on them.

**NB:** Note, that `MySQL-python` needs to be mentioned [twice](https://superuser.com/a/998313). As mentioned above, the first occurrence is the name of the package to apply the `no-binary` option to, the second specifies the package to install.

Comment: thanks, that helped but I also had to use `pip install --no-binary MySQL-python MySQL-python` to avoid using a cached wheel

Comment: Only python 2. Python 3 is not yet supported. :/

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and re-installing mysql-python and am still having the same problem. Any other thoughts on how to debug/fix the problem?

Comment: I was having this same error in Ruby + Rails after updating my local OS. I uninstalled the gem (`gem uninstall mysql2`) and in my case reinstalled using bundler (`bundle install`), but you could just `gem install mysql2`.

Comment: With typical pip install didn't work for me, but with --no-binary flag, it works! :D

Comment: It dit not worked for me until I used `pip install --no-cache-dir MYSQL-python`.

Comment: WOW okay tried for so long and @YerayDiazDiaz's answer finally worked for me!  Thanks so much @YerayDiazDiaz!!!  We should update the answer to show that.

Comment: mysqlclient has taken over from MySQL-python - `pip install mysqlclient` did the job for me on the new install of a project that formerly used MySQL-python (which hasn't been updated for years).

Answer (score 16):

You need to use dev version of `mysqlclient`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python.git@master
```

Before I had the lastest PyPI version (1.3.7) on Python 3.4 and it was searching for `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` (from MySQL 5.6) whereas I had only `libmysqlclient.20.dylib`(from MySQL 5.7).

If you use Python 3, `MySQL-python` is not an option (and `mysqlclient` is its newer version).

Comment: Definitely helped me with my setup: Mac OS X, brew installed python and mysql.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Big question is, why after **more than 18 months is the develop version not yet released?!?**

Answer (score 9):

If encountered a problem with lacking of `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`:

1. download mysql 5.6 from official link: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
2. install it
3. in terminal - `mdfind libmysqlclient | grep .18.`
4. copy the output
5. `sudo ln -s [the output from previous command] /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`